# ROS Answers SE migration: Roboteq AX2550

Tags: ros, motor-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Does anyone know if there is a package for the Roboteq AX2550 motor driver that is compatible with Groovy or Hydro? I've been looking around, but all I can find is an old package from Electric that I can't get working. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78951/roboteq-ax2550/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2013-09-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nevermind, a catkinized version of serial_utils and ax2550 has been developed and released for Hydro by wjwwood on github. Here is a link to the issue thread: https://github.com/wjwwood/serial/issues/40#issuecomment-24708776

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2013-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0